# Android - Display loading bar when calling API with retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit

In my app i am using retrofit 2 to retrieve data from a API. I have no problem about this. The problem is that i want to display a loading bar while this execution. The code is this

```
Call<MainInvestorProducts> call = apiInterface.getUseraccounts("Bearer "+bearerToken);

    mkLoader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<MainInvestorProducts>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<MainInvestorProducts> call, Response<MainInvestorProducts> response) {

            // If success response set the textViews
            if (response.code() == 200) {

                retrievedData = response.body();


                //else display error message
            }else if (response.code() == 401) {
                Toasty.error(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.expired_token),Toasty.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<MainInvestorProducts> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });

    mkLoader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

The problem is that mkloader is never show up.

My APIClient code

```
public class APIClient {

public static Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static Retrofit getClient(){

    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://api-test01.moneyboxapp.com")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build();

    return retrofit;
}
```

}

And this is an example of the Interface

```
@Headers({
        "AppId: 3a97b932a9d449c981b595",
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "appVersion: 5.10.0",
        "apiVersion: 3.0.0"
})
@POST("/users/login")
Call<MainUserLogin> logInUser(@Body LoginBody loginBody);
```

Answer (score 0):

Before calling the api you should start showing the loader (be sure that the api call is going to happen) and when once completed dismiss that

Comment: I update my code, but still not working.I dont know if the process is very fast or running in the same thread.

Answer (score 0):

```
    mkLoader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Call<MainInvestorProducts> call = apiInterface.getUseraccounts("Bearer "+bearerToken);

call.enqueue(new Callback<MainInvestorProducts>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<MainInvestorProducts> call, Response<MainInvestorProducts> response) {

        // If success response set the textViews
        if (response.code() == 200) {

            retrievedData = response.body();


            //else display error message
        }else if (response.code() == 401) {
            Toasty.error(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.expired_token),Toasty.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<MainInvestorProducts> call, Throwable t) {
    mkLoader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});
```

you just need to make the loader visibility to VISIBLE before calling the API and in case the api is succes or failure you set visibility to GONE